# ODS Excel / Proc Report - no wordwrap / merged cells?

Tags: sas

I use SAS ODS a lot to export prettied up excel files.  One in particular has titles that go significantly longer than the width of all of the columns, so they word wrap, which makes the file look horrible.

Is there any way to export a file with word wrap turned off?  I've searched on the SAS support forums, and have found very little helpful information.

```
%let myfile = "C:\Users\dicegods\testfile.xlsx"; 
ods excel file=&myfile. options (orientation='portrait' sheet_name='Baseball' embedded_titles='yes'); 

options LeftMargin=0.25in RightMargin=0.25in TopMargin=0.25in BottomMargin=0.25in; 
proc report data=sashelp.baseball; 
column name nHome nHits; 
define name / display 'Name'; 
define nHome / display 'Homers' sum; 
define nHits / analysis 'Hits' sum; 
title; title1 J=L "Baseball Players from SAS Help Database - sashelp library inEG - more run on stuff"; 
run;
```

Comment: can you also add a small snippet of code with which this issue could be reproduced?

Comment: `%let myfile = "C:\Users\dicegods\testfile.xlsx";

ods excel file=&myfile.
options (orientation='portrait' sheet_name='Baseball' embedded_titles='yes');
options LeftMargin=0.25in RightMargin=0.25in TopMargin=0.25in BottomMargin=0.25in;
proc report data=sashelp.baseball;
column name nHome nHits;

define name / display 'Name';
define nHome / display 'Homers' sum;
define nHits / analysis 'Hits' sum;

title;
title1 J=L "Baseball Players from SAS Help Database - sashelp library in EG - more run on stuff";
run;
`

Comment: This is a simplified example, the real one is information that I'd rather not post here.  Same issue though.  Ideally, I'd like the titles to just flow across the page.  I know I could increase the column widths of the pages, but really would rather not do that since it would make the data itself poorly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ODS TEXT. The following code snippet shows a simple way to use ODS TEXT to insert a "title" into the top of the sheet being generated by the following PROC step. Look up the [documentation](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=odsug&docsetTarget=p14gx25pepks6dn1q9m7vkq3gfoi.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) on ODS TEXT to see how to control the formatting of the generated text

```
%let myfile = "C:\downloads\testfile.xlsx"; 
ods excel file=&myfile. options (orientation='portrait' sheet_name='Baseball' embedded_titles='no'); 
ods text="Baseball Players from SAS Help Database - sashelp library inEG - more run on stuff"; 

options LeftMargin=0.25in RightMargin=0.25in TopMargin=0.25in BottomMargin=0.25in; 
proc report data=sashelp.baseball; 
column name nHome nHits; 
define name / display 'Name'; 
define nHome / display 'Homers' sum; 
define nHits / analysis 'Hits' sum; 
title J=L "Baseball Players from SAS Help Database - sashelp library inEG - more run on stuff"; 
run; 
title;

ods excel close;
```

Comment: can you also explain how using ODS TEXT in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. The code shows a simple way to uses ODS TEXT to insert a "title" into the top of the sheet being generated by the following PROC step.  Look up the documentation on ODS TEXT to see how to control the formatting of the generated text.

Comment: I meant to ask, how ODS TEXT helped in the scenario. I've edited your answer to include your comment reply as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this option, FLOW, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Modified it slightly to remove 'enter image description here' but then I had to add more text because there's a 30 character minimum for an answer.

Comment: I need the opposite of that option.  I want wrap text and merged cells turned _off_.  I tried the flow option for my header range, as well as the flow for the rest, neither worked.

Comment: I reckon I have misunderstood your issue.  I thought you wanted to turn off the insertion of LF characters.